# Mixed ftp ssh permission problem

Tags: ssh, web-server, ftp, chmod, permissions

I'm running a webserver and I've setup two groups. One with just me, and another with me and a collaborator. I've chmodded to 755 my htdocs folder and I gave a specifically "upload" dir the group shared with my collab. So now my collab (via sym link) is able to upload some files via sftp, but he can also traversing all the directories of the web server. I've the chmodded to -R 751 the htdocs dir, and now he is not able to see everything, but the web server (obviusly) doesn't work anymore until I restore the original permission.

Do you guys have any guess?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the ftp server, you can chroot him to a particular subdirectory.  Search for the name of your ftp server (e.g. vsftpd, pure-ftpd, proftpd) and "chroot"